# Nodejs Api call in background

Tags: node.js, rest

I'm developing an app with node JS, the app generates a report calling the endpoint api.example.com/generate-report

But this report takes around 1 minute on be generated, then I want to implement something like this:

1. User click on generate report
2. System return response {generating:"ok"}
3. After the system generate the report send a notification (this I what I know how to do)
4. User get the report

Is this possible with nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I do some research, this can be easily done using Promises.

To run the following code it's necessary to install express and node uuid

```
npm install --save express
npm install --save uuid
node index.js
```

The source code of index is:

```
//index.js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const uuidV1 = require('uuid/v1');

// this is where we'll store the results of our jobs by uuid once they're done
const JOBS = {};

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("It works!");
});

app.get("/startjob", (req, res) => {
  let times = [100, 1000, 10000, 20000];
  let promises = [];
  for (let time of times) {
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, time, `${time} is done.`);
    }));
  }
  // obviously, you'd want to generate a real uuid here to avoid collisions
  let uuid = uuidV1();
  console.log(uuid);
  Promise.all(promises).then(values => { JOBS[uuid] = values; });
  res.redirect(`progress/${uuid}`);
});

app.get("/progress/:uuid", (req, res) => {
  if (JOBS[req.params.uuid] === undefined) {
    res.send("Still processing your request.");
  } else {
    res.send(`Here's your result: ${JOBS[req.params.uuid]}.`);
    // instead of immediately deleting the result of the job (and making it impossible for the user
    // to fetch it a second time if they e.g. accidentally cancel the download), it would be better
    // to run a periodic cleanup task on `JOBS`
    delete JOBS[req.params.uuid];
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on localhost:${PORT}.`);
});
```

When the code runs you will be redirected to /process/uuid and I get the status of the process.

This needs some improvements because I want the response like "{process:uuid}" and I can store this on my Local Storage to use after.

Well, I hope this help to someone.